# Why "a creeper climbs" in Our Casuarina Tree by Toru Dutt?

Tags: poetry, wording-choice, toru-dutt

In the poem ["Our Casuarina Tree"](https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/our-casuarina-tree/) by Toru Dutt, why has she written 'a creeper climbs...'?
Instead, she might have written 'a climber climbs'! Does it imply anything?

Comment: "A climber climbs" would seem oddly repetitive and pleonastic. Is there reason to think the specific words "a creeper climbs" have any particular significance?

Comment: A "creeper" is a much more common word for a vine (which is what she is talking about) than a "climber".

Answer (score 2):

The context for this phrase is:

> Like a huge Python, winding round and round
> The rugged trunk, indented deep with scars,
> Up to its very summit near the stars,
> **A creeper climbs**, in whose embraces bound
> No other tree could live. But gallantly
> The giant wears the scarf, and flowers are hung
> In crimson clusters all the boughs among,

A ‘creeper’ is

> A plant that creeps along the ground, or (more usually) one that ascends a supporting surface, as ivy and the Virginian Creeper (*Ampelopsis hederacea*)
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*</sub>

In this sense it is synonymous with ‘climber’, and Google Books Ngram Viewer suggests that the two terms have had broadly similar popularity in English:

[image]

Nonetheless I think the choice of ‘creeper’ is significant because the plant is compared to a python, and ‘to creep’ means:

> To move with the body prone and close to the ground […] Formerly said of snakes, worms, and other creatures without limbs
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*</sub>

so that ‘creeper’ emphasizes the snake-like behaviour of the plant in a way that ‘climber’ would not. And a third sense of ‘creeper’ is

> One who moves stealthily […] or proceeds in a mean and servile way.
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*</sub>

which suggests the way that a parasitic plant depends on its host for support and yet slowly and inimically strangles it.

Comment: Now the implication is clear, thank you!